# What's the difference between a VLA and dynamic memory allocation via malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, malloc, variable-length-array

I was curious with this:

What is the diference between:

```
const int MAX_BUF = 1000;
char* Buffer = malloc(MAX_BUF);
```

and:

```
char Buffer[MAX_BUF];
```

Comment: Is the second example really a VLA, given that `MAX_BUF` is `const`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sir, if i'm not wrong, in `C++`, a `const` variable is a constant, but in `C` a `const` variable is actually `const`-qualified, not an actual constant. So, the second one is VLA, Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh OK, thanks. It was a genuine question. I don't know that much C.

Comment: @juanchopanza My `C++` skills are horrible, I am almost invisible in that case. Just "happen" to know some case(s), like this one. :-)

Comment: which code requires less time to execute?

Answer (score 16):

- Case 1: In

  ```
   char Buffer[MAX_BUF];
  ```

  `Buffer` is an ***array*** of size `MAX_BUF`. The allocation technique is called [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).
- Case 2: In

  ```
  const int MAX_BUF = 1000;
  char* Buffer = malloc(MAX_BUF);
  ```

  `Buffer` is a ***pointer*** which is allocated a memory of size `MAX_BUF` which is `1000`.

and, an array is **not** the same as a pointer, and [C-FAQ has a Very Good collection detailing the reasons](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

The major difference, in terms of usability and behaviour are:

1. (1) is on stack, usually <sup>Note</sup>,  while (2) is on heap, always.
2. (1) has fixed size  once allocated, (2) can be resized.
3. (1) is allocated when the enclosing function is called and has the block scope OTOH, (2) is allocated memory dynamically, at runtime and the returned memory has a lifetime which extends from the allocation until the deallocation.
4. (1) allocated memory need not be managed by programmer, while in (2) all `malloc()`d  memory should be `free()`d. <sup>[<kbd>Courtesy: [Giorgi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3963067/giorgi)</kbd>]</sup>

---

<sup>Note: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#Memory)</sup>

> <sup>For example, the GNU C Compiler allocates memory for VLAs on the stack.</sup>

Comment: Aside: "while (2) is on heap, always." --> not always.  The notion of heap, stack and allocation details are implementation defined.  The remaining 3 points are good.

Answer (score 5):

I will add a bit info in terms of memory management, in addition to what others said.

1) The main difference is here:

```
const int MAX_BUF = 1000;
char* Buffer = malloc(MAX_BUF);
```

You need to manage the allocated memory manually, e.g., free `Buffer` when you are done using it. Forgetting to `free` it (or freeing it twice) may lead to trouble.

2) With the second case:

```
char Buffer[MAX_BUF];
```

You don't need to free anything. It will get destroyed automatically. Hence you avoid the task of handling the memory - which is good.
You should try to evaluate always which approach you need.

Some points.

- Since second is allocated on stack, the first approach is taken also when large array needs to be created - since more memory is usually available on the heap.
- Also if you create array using second approach for example in the method, the life time of the object will be that method - you will not be able to use that array outside that method. Whereas with dynamic allocation that is not the case.

Comment: Nice. `free()`-ing angle was required which both me and @coolguy missed. :-)

Comment: I added that, with attributes. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I see, nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* Buffer = malloc(MAX_BUF);
```

creates a `char` pointer `Buffer`, dynamically allocates `MAX_BUF` bytes of memory via the `malloc` and makes `Buffer` point to the start of the allocated space. This memory is allocated on the heap.

```
char Buffer[MAX_BUF];
```

creates an array `Buffer` of size `MAX_BUF` which can hold a maximum of `MAX_BUF` characters. Note that you are creating a [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (a feature introduced in [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)) since `MAX_BUF` is a variable. This array may be created on the stack.

Comment: Note that technically, the array is a VLA (variable-length array) because `MAX_BUF` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

The most notable difference is scope. The VLA array will only be valid inside the scope where it is declared, while a dynamic array will be available everywhere in the program until you call `free()`.

In practice, VLAs may be faster than dynamic memory, in case the compiler use stack allocation for the VLA. It is however not specified by the C standard where a VLA is allocated.

(A compiler could in theory allocate a VLA on the heap, but then the compiler would also be responsible for the clean-up. I don't think any such solutions exist. Every compiler I've used always declare VLAs on the stack.)

This means that VLAs are unsuitable to hold large amounts of data: you would risk stack overflow. This is not a concern when you are using dynamic memory however.

VLAs don't have the same portability as dynamic arrays, since awfully old compilers don't support VLAs. In theory, new C11 compilers don't have to suport VLAs either, though at this point I know of no compiler has been stupid enough to drop that support.

---

Comparison/summary:

- VLAs should be used when there are small amounts of local data, because they have fast allocation time and automatic clean-up.
- Dynamic arrays should be used when there are large amounts of data, to prevent stack overflow.
- Dynamic arrays should be used when the data needs to persist after the execution of a function and be available elsewhere in the program.
- Dynamic arrays should be used when you have exceptional and/or irrational portability requirements.

Comment: And also, Linus Torvald [hates VLA](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/7/621) ;)