# Porting code from C++ to C. How do I deal with this vector and range based loop

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to port to C. Since there's no vectors in C, I used a normal array, but I don't know how I'm going to deal with the ranged based loop on line 18.

```
    for (int u : d[i]) if (dfs(rev[u])) {
        par[i] = u;
        rev[u] = i;
        return true;
    }
```

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
const int Maxn = 200;
vector<int> d[Maxn];
int par[Maxn];
int rev[Maxn];
bool vs[Maxn];
bool dfs(int i) {
    if (i < 0) return true;
    if (vs[i]) return false;
    vs[i] = true;
    for (int u : d[i]) if (dfs(rev[u])) {
        par[i] = u;
        rev[u] = i;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        getline(cin, s);
        stringstream ss(s);
        vector<int> mk(n, 1);
        mk[i] = 0;
        int x;
        while (ss >> x)
            mk[x] = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
            if (mk[x])
                d[i].push_back(x);
    }
    memset(par, -1, sizeof par);
    memset(rev, -1, sizeof rev);
    for (bool ok = true; ok; ) {
        ok = false;
        memset(vs, 0, sizeof vs);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (par[i] < 0) {
                ok |= dfs(i);
            }
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ans += (par[i] < 0);
    cout << ans;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to other site with code, post the code here in your question.

Comment: `for (int u = 0; u < sizeof(d)/sizeof(int); i++) { if (dfs(rev[u])) { ... return true; } }`

Comment: @Elie Kahwaji I see that `d` is an array of vectors in your C++ code. When I edited my answer, I did not notice that. How did you convert `d` in your C code, as `int **d`?

Comment: It depends on how you have mapped an array of `std::vector<int>`  (which is what `d` is) to C.   Since a `std::vector` encapsulates a resizable dynamically allocated array, there are many ways you could do that mapping, which in turn would affect how you handle loops.   You have given NO INFORMATION AT ALL on how you have done that mapping, so cannot expect useful help.   Voting to close accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C there is no `std::vector`, the closes would be an array.

```
int array[] = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ];

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof *array; ++i)
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
```

If you get a pointer of an array of int, the you have to pass the length of
the array as well, as `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` works with arrays only.

```
void foo(in *array, size_t len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
}

void bar(void)
{
    int array[] = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ];

    foo(array, sizeof array / sizeof *array);
}
```

**edit 2**

*I noticed that you've posted your code and that `d` is declared as `vector<int> d[Maxn];`. Also taking in consideration your recent comment*

> So this is an array of vectors. Do you have any idea how i can work with arrays taking that in consideration in C

There a couple of ways to convert the array of vectors in C. But this depends
on your needs. If for example you know that all vectors are going to have the
same size (for example `int vectsize = 100`), then you can create a two
dimensional array with the sizes<sup>1</sup>

```
int Maxn = 200;
int vectsize = 100;

int d[Maxn][vectsize];
memset(d, 0, sizeof d); // initialize all elements with 0

// filling the data
for(int i = 0; i < Maxn; ++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j < vectsize; ++j)
        d[i][j] = get_value_for(i, j); 
}
```

The the range-loop is very easy:

```
// assuming that the variables i, par, rev are valid, i between 0 and Maxn-1
for(int j = 0; j < vectsize; ++j)
{
    int u = d[i][j];
    if (dfs(rev[u])) {
        par[i] = u;
        rev[u] = i;
        return true;
    } 
}
```

It gets a little more complicated if you only know one dimension, for example
every vector in the array could have a different size.

```
d[0].size() --> 10
d[1].size() --> 1
d[2].size() --> 3
...
```

The you can create an array of pointers to `int`, but you would have to keep
another array of `int`s with the length for every `d[i]` vector.

```
int Maxn = 200;
int *d[Maxn]; // pointer to int[Maxn] arrays
int vectsize[Maxn];

// initializing with 0
memset(d, 0, sizeof d);
memset(vectsize, 0, sizeof vectsize);

// filling the data
for(int i = 0; i < Maxn; ++i)
{
    vectsize[i] = get_length_for(i);
    d[i] = malloc(vectsize[i] * sizeof *d[i]);
    if(d[i] == NULL)
        // error handling

    for(j = 0; j < vectsize[i]; ++j)
        d[i][j] = get_value_for(i, j); 
}
```

Note that I'm using here (and in the last example) `get_length_for()` and `get_value_for()` as placeholders<sup>2</sup>.

Now your range-base loop would look like this:

```
// assuming that the variables i, par, rev are valid, i between 0 and Maxn-1
for(int j = 0; j < vectsize[i]; ++j)
{
    int u = d[i][j];
    if (dfs(rev[u])) {
        par[i] = u;
        rev[u] = i;
        return true;
    } 
}
```

At some point however you would have to free the memory:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Maxn; ++i)
    free(d[i]);
```

The third option would be using a double pointer and using `malloc`/`realloc`
to allocate the memory. This is the more general solution, but you have to
take care of memory management and that can be sometimes difficult, especially when you
haven't programmed in C to much. But also in case where both dimension are unknown, this is the way to go:

```
int Maxn = get_some_maxn_value();
int **d, *vectsize;

d = malloc(Maxn * sizeof *d);
if(d == NULL)
    // error handling

vectsize = malloc(Maxn * sizeof *vectsize);
if(vectsize == NULL)
    // error handling,
    // if you exit the function, don't forget
    // to do free(d) first as part of the
    // error handling

// initialize all elements with 0
memset(d, 0, Maxn * sizeof *d);
memset(vectsize, 0, Maxn * sizeof *vectsize);

// filling the data (the same as above)
for(int i = 0; i < Maxn; ++i)
{
    vectsize[i] = get_length_for(i);
    d[i] = malloc(vectsize[i] * sizeof *d[i]);
    if(d[i] == NULL)
        // error handling

    for(j = 0; j < vectsize[i]; ++j)
        d[i][j] = get_value_for(i, j); 
}
```

In this case the range-loop would look exactly as for the array of pointers.
Freeing the memory is a little bit different though:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Maxn; ++i)
    free(d[i]);
free(d);
free(vectsize);
```

Like I said earlier, which one of these three methods to use depends on the way
the original C++ code fills the values, how long the vectors are, etc. Judging
form the C++ code you posted, you read an integer from the user and store it
in `n`. Then you read more values from the user and push then in the vector
`d[i]` for all `i` between 0 and `Maxn-1`. It seems that all vectors have at
most length `n`, but because of

```
if (mk[x])
    d[i].push_back(x);
```

they also could have less than `n` elements. That's why I think that the third
solution is preferable here.

---

*Annotations*

<sup>1</sup>Prior to C99, *Variable Length Arrays* (VLA) were not supported, so if you had the
dimension in a variable, you had to use `malloc` to allocate enough memory.
C99 supports VLAs, but I'm not quite sure how well supported they are and/or
whether your compiler supports them.

I personally don't use them in my code at all, that's why I really don't know. I compiled this examples with GNU
GCC 6.4.0 (on linux) and they worked fine.

The first two options use VLAs, if your compiler doesn't support that, then
you have to use the third option.

For more information about VLAs:

- [malloced array VS. variable-length-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672322/malloced-array-vs-variable-length-array)
- [What's the difference between a VLA and dynamic memory allocation via malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199566/whats-the-difference-between-a-vla-and-dynamic-memory-allocation-via-malloc)
- [Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)
- [GCC manual: 6.19 Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (in case you ise GCC)

<sup>2</sup>How you really get this values depends on the original C++ code.
So far I've only looked very briefly over your C++ code. Using the values from
my example `get_length_for(0)` would return 10, `get_length_for(1)` would return 1,
`get_length_for(2)` would return 3, etc.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I pressed saved to quickly without reviewing my own answer, I fixed the mistakes, thank you for the feedback. But *`d.size()` is not defined*. I said *`d` should be `vector`*.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Ah stupid me, of course, at that point I was still thinking in C++. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Ok, for stupid mistakes like this, the downvote is deserved. It would be nice however, if the person downvoting leaves comments so that the answers can be fixed.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-are-my-questions-on-stack-overflow-getting-downvotes-without-explanation

Comment: @Tibrogargan thanks for the link. It was deserved, I should have read my answer before hitting *Post your answer*, I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: So this is an array of vectors. Do you have any idea how i can work with arrays taking that in consideration in C.

Comment: @ElieKahwaji yes, I'm editing right now my answer to address your last comment, it will take me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Alright, ill check this section tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ElieKahwaji I made an update of my answer, hope this help you.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you so much with your help. One last thing, what can I do about the second vector (the mk vector) also I tried replacing the stringstream with char pointer but I have no idea how to deal with the >> operator with C or how to iterate that while loop in C

Comment: @ElieKahwaji This is getting out of hand, there are too many questions and I don't want my answer to be longer. It would be best if you start a new question just focusing on how to translate the vector and stringstream mechanics into C. `mk` is vector that has `n` elements all initialized with 1. Read the first part of my answer, it tells you how to emulate the behaviour of vectors with arrays, with that you can convert `mk` (to be continued)

Comment: @ElieKahwaji the stringstream is used to parse the values. The user enter a line like `1 2 3 4 5` and every number is assigned to `x` and push into the vector. In C you would have to use something like `sscanf` or `strtok` to get the values and put them in the array.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming d[i] is a vector, this is a similar loop:

```
for (size_t s = 0; s < d[i].size(); s++)
{
    int u = d[i][s];
    if (dfs(rev[u]))
    {
        par[i] = u;
        rev[u] = i;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a string. I made it a string because vectors dont exist in c

Comment: It's still likely to work the same way as your range-based loop.

Comment: what is a `vector`?  `d[i].size()` is not defined

Comment: d[i] is a vector.  Just look at his latest update to his code.

Comment: C does not have `vector`.  Since the OP's premise is literally "Since there's no vectors in C", it's odd that you believe your answer should include them

Comment: I did not set out to do his job for him.  I showed him an alternative way to look at the C++ code, so that he can convert it to C himself.

Comment: Then this is not an answer and should be a comment on the question.  (Flagged as such)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163081/discussion-between-sid-s-and-tibrogargan).

Comment: at very minimum its highly confusing, we can see the the OP tried to compile yr code snippet as C