# Not allowed to initialize an array of class in Visual Studio 2019 despite using C++14

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I was trying to make an array of class, but Visual Studio is showing an error `Compiler Error C2131` which means `"An expression declared as const or constexpr didn't evaluate to a constant at compile time. The compiler must be able to determine the value of the expression at the point it's used."`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class instructor
{
public:
    string name;
};

int main(void)
{
    const int num=0;
    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> num;

    instructor student[num];

    return 0;
}
```

This being the error shown

```
Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant
Error (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value
```

[image: image for the version of c++]

What could be the possible fix for this, rather than dynamic allocation?

NOTE:- But the same code is allowed in GCC code-blocks.

Comment: dynamic allocation is the answer, however you can encapsulate that by using a `std::vector` as your "array".

Comment: Whoever told you that variable-length arrays is a feature of C++14 wasn't telling the truth.

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter if you are using C++14, 17, or 20, or any version below 14.  Arrays must be declared using a compile-time expression denoting the number of entries.  If you were using g++ before using Visual C++, then g++ fooled you into thinking you can declare arrays like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035501/why-is-this-code-considered-a-vla-even-though-it-uses-an-int, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303820/creation-of-dynamic-array-of-dynamic-objects-in-c/20304088

Comment: @NathanOliver Or indeed an `std::array` rather than a C-style array

Comment: @Nick Not when the OP wants to use a size taken from the user.

Comment: @NathanOliver Huh, TIL, apparently there's an extension for it (`dynarray`). Always forget that `std::array` size is a template parameter :facepalm:

Comment: There is no `dynarray` in standard C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well I did say "extension" :p

Comment: [This program does not result in the error you have posted](https://godbolt.org/z/qjGW97vTn).