# How do I input n elements in a VLA and print them?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
//print els of an array

int main(){
    int n,arr[n],i;

    printf("\nenter no. of elements in the array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\nenter elements of the array : ");
    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        printf("\n%d ",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Move the `scanf` to be above `arr[n]`. That is, need to have a value for `n` before declaring the array.

Comment: `n` is uninitialized before the `scanf()`, do `int arr[n]` *after* `scanf("%d",&n);`.

Comment: thnx kaylum & lonely programmer :)

Comment: Please create an answer.

Comment: Don't use VLA for something like this! If you do it anyway, check the value of `n` **before** creating the VLA to ensure that it isn't "too big"

Comment: Also note that compiler support for VLAs is optional from C11 on (though most compilers do support VLA, it is no longer guaranteed)

Answer (score 1):

To create a VLA you need to know the length provided by the user first before creating the array, so Just as [JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10878623/justasimplelonelyprogrammer) stated, you should only create the array after reading the value of n.

```c
scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[n];
```

However, dynamic memory allocation is the more *usual* solution to this problem.

```c
int* arr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Please refer to this answer for [difference between dynamic memory allocation and VLA.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199566/whats-the-difference-between-a-vla-and-dynamic-memory-allocation-via-malloc).