# Weird segmentation faut (core dumbed)- The C Programming Language Exercise 13

Tags: c

Hey currently I am working on exercise 13 of K&R - The C programming language.
So far I have the following Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 99

int main() {
  struct termios old_tio, new_tio;

  /* get the terminal settings for stdin */
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_tio);

  /* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
  new_tio = old_tio;

  /* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
  new_tio.c_lflag &= (~ICANON & ~ECHO);

  /* set the new settings immediately */
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_tio);

  int c, length, lengthArray[ARRAY_SIZE], word, lastChar, longestWord;

  word = 0;
  longestWord = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != 'q') {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
      if (lastChar != ' ' && lastChar != '\t' && lastChar != '\n') {
        lengthArray[word] = length;
        word++;
        length = 0;
      }
    } else {
      length++;
      if (length > longestWord)
        longestWord = length;
    }
    putchar(c);
    lastChar = c;
  }

  int histogram[longestWord];
  for (int i = 0; i < longestWord; i++) {
    histogram[i] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < word; i++) {
    histogram[lengthArray[i]] += 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < longestWord; i++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, histogram[i]);
  }

  /* restore the former settings */
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old_tio);

  return 0;
}
```

Everytime I run it I get a segmantation fault, unless I comment out the last for loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < longestWord; i++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, histogram[i]);
  }
```

Commenting out the printf statement doesn't help so the for loop is the problem.
(The actual exercise code starts at `int c, length, lengthArray`. The Termios stuff is just for disabling canonical mode in the terminal)

Comment: Try allocating a pointer with malloc() instead.
I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Please note that `lastChar` is not initialized.

Comment: `length` isn't initialized and there is no `exercise 13` in `K&R`.

Comment: Thanks the initialization was the problem.
I meant exercise 1-13. Why does it work if I remove the for-loop? Since the loop doesn't use the uninitialized variables?

Comment: Put the terminal code into two functions that you call from `main()`.  That declutters your code

Answer (score -1):

int histogram[longestWord];
In an array declaration, the size must be known at compile time. You cant specify a size that histogram known only at runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199566/whats-the-difference-between-a-vla-and-dynamic-memory-allocation-via-malloc They were introduced with C99, while the asker mentions K&R, though.

Comment: Variable length arrays are legal in C. Whether they're a good idea or not is another issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).